# Not enough memory to load specified image

Tags: boot, system-installation, ram

I built a computer recently and I've tried to use Ubuntu and Linux Mint, both trying to install from a 32gb USB 2.0 flash drive, without success. There is no other operating system on the computer and with each OS I get the same error:

```
Not enough memory to load specified image.
boot: _
```

I'm new to Linux, so I don't know whether this is related to the OS.

Hardware details:

- Ryzen 3 1300x
- MSI x370 gaming plus motherboard
- 8g Kingston hyper fury x black ddr4
- nvidia gtx 760
- evga 500w b psu
- toshiba 500gb ssd

I need to resolve this quickly if possible

[image: Not enough memory... in monospace font on blueish screen]

Comment: I don't know your system; but the message used to be the result of issues with BIOS (both linux & windoze) where part of memory is reserved for hardware creating a 'hole' in the map.  I don't know sorry, but look for memory reservations in bios...

Comment: Does the bootable USB work well on other computers? The boot: prompt looks similar to grub

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities -

```
1) Puppy is not running 64bit

2) Puppy has smaller memory footprint
```

I see that this problem has been around for years, the only convincing solution so far is to disable "Memory hole" the BIOS setting. The rest of us who do not have this option seems pretty much stuck.

Comment: could you explain the reference to Puppy?

Answer (score 1):

As per suggestion [from this article](https://www.elivecd.org/ufaqs/error-booting-usb-not-enough-memory-load-specified-image/), adding a `mem` parameter resolved my issue.

Summary:

> *You should try to append the boot parameter mem=1952M or other values to the boot parameters (pressing TAB key in the first boot menu). This parameter tells the kernel how much memory your computer has, sometimes the BIOS does not provide the correct number, so you need to specify it.*
>
> *Note: this option doesn’t always work on the first try, so you may need to play with different values, like 1024M (even if you have 4G), 512M, 2G, etc…*

Comment: You should explain the answer here, and not just provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Disable any "memory hole" in the BIOS settings and try again
2. Reset BIOS settings to defaults and try again
3. Flash latest BIOS and try again